# Unexpected angle bracket "<" in numpy multiply() of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How does `adj.multiply(adj.T > adj)` work?

The code runs fine but I don't expect an angle bracket `>` in a multiply statement. I believe the docs stated to provide two values to `multiply()`, but it's still working and producing an output matrix by replacing `(adj.T > adj)` with `(True)`, `(False)`, `(adj.T != adj)`, but not `(adj.T = adj)`. Also, that `multiply()` method is not attached on the end of a variable, whereas it is used as `adj.multiply()` here. The source of the method multiply seemed to just convert it to a csr_matrix and run numpy's `multiply()`, then IIRC converts it back to coo_matrix. The `.T` of course means "transpose".

```
# build symmetric adjacency matrix
adj = adj + adj.T.multiply(adj.T > adj) - adj.multiply(adj.T > adj)`
```

For some context, "adj" is a scipy coo_matrix from [graph convolutional network](https://github.com/tkipf/pygcn/blob/master/pygcn/utils.py) on github, which I'm trying to understand how the input is prepared for.

```
adj = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(edges.shape[0]), (edges[:, 0], edges[:, 1])),
                    shape=(labels.shape[0], labels.shape[0]),
                    dtype=np.float32)
```

Attempting to reproduce the code requires running that whole page.

The following is easier to recreate and test:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

asdf = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(5), (np.ones(5), np.ones(5))), shape=(5,5), 
dtype=np.float32)
print(asdf)
print(asdf.toarray())
asdf = asdf + asdf.T.multiply(asdf.T > asdf) - asdf.multiply(asdf.T > asdf)
print("asdf")
print(asdf.toarray())
```

at row=1,col=1, value was 5, where a `asdf.T.multiply(True)` statement doubled its value 5, to 10. Passing two variables separated by space or comma doesn't work.

---

**Update:**

I placed a number (not a whole matrix) before the ">" angle bracket and it produced this error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:287: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing a sparse matrix with a scalar greater than zero using < is inefficient, try using >= instead.
>     warn(bad_scalar_msg, SparseEfficiencyWarning)

Seeing that, I realized that there was a different sparse multiply() method that didn't show in google without explicitly typing "sparse". Its [documentation is here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html), but I don't see how it handles an angle bracket or condition.

Comment: Did you look at the output of `adj.T > adj`?

Comment: Using numpy.savetxt(), it's a 175Mb txt file of walls (as far as you can scroll horizontally and vertically) of "0.000000000000000000e+00". I found a couple 1's.

Comment: Yes, it'll all be zero (not larger) or 1 (larger).

Comment: C++ has angle brackets `std::vector<int>` as well as comparisons `x < 4`.  Python not having the former, what do you think that character means?

Comment: I expect to pass the method `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply()` a scalar or matrix. Seeing a comparison in use with this method is the confusion. Is it going to multiply by the larger number(or matrix value) if the condition is true?

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code, I consistently find the `multiply()` will multiply by a scalar or matrix value, but with a condition, it performs the operator previous to it if the condition is true, without performing a multiplication.

For example, the following:

```
asdf = asdf + asdf.T.multiply(True)
```

will only perform the `+` operation because of the `True` boolean being passed. In this case there is no multiplication. Same results, if instead of `True` we have `3>2`, which is true, (it doesn't multiply by the 3 or 2).

```
row = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
col = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])

asdf = sp.coo_matrix(([1,2,3,4,5], (row, col)), shape=(5,5), dtype=np.float32)
print(asdf)
print(asdf.toarray())
asdf = asdf + asdf.T.multiply(2 < 3) - asdf.multiply(7 != 8)
print("asdf")
print(asdf.toarray())
```

Comment: This `asdf` just a diagonal nonzero values - and the calculation changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**Make a record for this problem.**

When I try to handle confusion about this line of code:

```
adj = adj + adj.T.multiply(adj.T > adj) - adj.multiply(adj.T > adj)
```

I need to understand three parts:

**1. adj.T > adj**

It builds a bool type matrix with the same shape of matrix adj.

**2. multiply()**

The function achieves Hadamard product actually, rather than Dot product. The official document gives the description: "Point-wise multiplication by another matrix".

**3. the way to build symmetric adjacency matrix**

We'd better reserve the larger weight item between (i, j) and (j, i) instead of adding them together simply, as the latter will add the weight of the edge.

**There is the code to explain them:**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp  
row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])

A = sp.coo_matrix(([0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0], (row, col)),
                  shape=(3, 3), dtype=np.float32)
print(A.toarray())
print((A.T > A).toarray())
print(A.T.multiply(A.T > A).toarray())

A = A + A.T.multiply(A.T > A) - A.multiply(A.T > A)
print("The symmetric adjacency matrix:", A.toarray(), sep='\n')
```