# Building a symmetric adjacency matrix of a given sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am finding it hard to understand the following piece of code which constructs a sparse adjacency matrix of a given sparse matrix.

```
# build symmetric adjacency matrix
adj = adj + adj.T.multiply(adj.T > adj) - adj.multiply(adj.T > adj)
```

This is what I tried out:

```
adj =np.array([[2. , 0., 0. ],
           [3. , 0. , 0. ],
           [3. , 0. , 0. ]])
adjs=sp.coo_matrix(adj)
adjs.T.todense()

#matrix([[2., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])

adjs.T.multiply(adjs.T > adjs).todense()

#matrix([[0., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])

q= adjs+adjs.T.multiply(adjs.T > adjs)+adjs - adjs.multiply(adjs.T > adjs)
q.todense()

matrix([[4., 3., 3.],
        [6., 0., 0.],
        [6., 0., 0.]])
```

In the output the diagonals are not zero.

The code is part of the graph convolutional network paper by Kipf and it's in the setup.py file here:

https://github.com/yao8839836/text_gcn/blob/b230e8083f838953646a9034b60abc5f69b062f6/utils.py#L176

I do not understand how that code makes a matrix symmetric. Can anyone give an explanation?

This question has been asked before [Unexpected angle bracket "<" in numpy multiply() of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580369/unexpected-angle-bracket-in-numpy-multiply-of-matrices)

But there is no explanation behind how that code works.In my example case I don't know why I got   diagonal elements to be non zero.

Comment: If the start matrix has nonzero diagonals, the symmtric version should have them as well.  Your `q` calculation has an extra `adjs`.  `q` should be symmetric.

Comment: This might be easier to play with using the numpy array equivalent, `adj + adj.T*(adj.T > adj) - adj*(adj.T > adj)`.  It's a sparse friendly version of  `np.maximum(adj, adj.T)`.

Comment: @hpaulj just noticed the error. Why do we add adj to this adj.T*(adj.T > adj)?